# How to select items from child table based on values in parent table?

Tags: sql

I have a table called tbl_PO and another table called tbl_PO_LineItems. In tbl_PO, the fields of relevance are 'PO#' and 'Status'. The 'Status' field has a few options, the one we're interested in for now is "Closed". Each PO has many line items, so there is a 1 to many relationship for the PO# in tbl_PO and the PO# in tbl_PO_LineItems. There is a field in tbl_PO_LineItems called 'LineNum', which is the line item number. There is another field called 'Code' which is a combination of the PO# and LineNum. I know this is a combined field but it makes the flow of data much easier in the rest of the database.

In a different table, call it tbl_table3, I want to be able to use an SQL statement along the lines of this:

`SELECT Code FROM tbl_PO_LineItems WHERE tbl_PO.Status = 'Closed'`

The problem is that there is no direct link from Code to any field in tbl_PO. I need to go through the PO# associated with that Code to get a Status value from tbl_PO for that PO#. How can I do this? I read up a bit on the JOIN command but I am not too comfortable with it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.PO_num, t2.Code
FROM tbl_PO t1
INNER JOIN tbl_PO_LineItems t2
    ON t1.PO_num = t2.PO_num
WHERE t1.Status = 'Closed'
```

I don't know how crazy I am about the combined column `Code`, but without more information I cannot make any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: It's unique to the field, consider it an ID for each line item, It's just we chose the naming convention for ease of use when selecting the Code in multiple other tables so we know what it is since it's made up of the PO#. Also could you explain what's happening in your code? Not sure what the t1 and t2 are.

Comment: @Michael The `t1` and `t2` are table _aliases_.  They can be used in place of the full table name, which can make a query more readable.

Comment: syntax : select aliasName.columnName FROM tableName aliasName;

Comment: @Michael you can use documentation for more info,

http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/topics

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not sure if you're familiar with ms-access but that's what I'm using, and when I use that code as a rowsource for my combobox, it tries to get me to enter the status as a parameter value. Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: Nevermind I got it working, just mistyped the tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options for you one with a join and one without. Let me know if this is what you're asking.(I wrote this off the top of my head but it should run)

```
SELECT * --you can choose your columns here
FROM tbl_PO AS PO, tbl_PO_LineItems AS LineItems
WHERE PO.ID = LineItems.PONumber
AND LineItems.Status = 'Closed
```

or with join

```
SELECT * 
FROM  tbl_PO AS PO
JOIN tbl_PO_LineItems AS LineItems
ON LineItems.PONumber = PO.ID
AND LineItems.Status = 'Closed
```